# grep: regex only for match anything between parenthesis

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How do I match word only between parenthesis

Input :
`this is (test.com)`

Desire Output :
`test.com`

Comment: Are you looking for a 'grep' regex to match, or, e.g., a 'sed' substitute command to generate your output shown?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here are a few options, all of which print the desired output:

1. Using `grep` with the `-o` flag (only print matching part of line) and Perl compatible regular expressions (`-P`) that can do [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

   ```
   printf "this is (test.com)\n" | grep -Po '(?<=\().*(?=\))'
   ```

   That regex might need some explaining:

   - `(?<=\()` : This is a *positive lookbehind*, the general format is `(?<=foo)bar` and that will match all cases of `bar` found right after `foo`. In this case, we are looking for an opening parenthesis, so we use `\(` to escape it.
   - `(?=\))` : This is a *positive lookahead* and simply matches the closing parenthesis.
2. The `-o` option to `grep` causes it to only print the matched part of any line, so we look for whatever is in parentheses and then delete them with `sed`:

   ```
   printf "this is (test.com)\n" | grep -o '(.*)' | sed 's/[()]//g'
   ```
3. Parse the whole thing with Perl:

   ```
   printf "this is (test.com)\n" | perl -pe 's/.*\((.+?)\)/$1/'
   ```
4. Parse the whole thing with `sed`:

   ```
   printf "this is (test.com)\n" | sed 's/.*(\(.*\))/\1/'
   ```

Answer (score 5):

One approach would be to use [PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.pcre.org/) with `grep`:

```
$ echo "this is (test.com)" | grep -oP '(?<=\().*(?=\))'
test.com
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info - lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)